# how to use emacs-pcre in Ubuntu

Tags: regex, emacs, pcre

I am trying to use perl compatible regex (PCRE) in Emacs. After some search, I found a git repo for [libpcre binding of Emacs Lisp](https://github.com/syohex/emacs-pcre/). The grammar in the sample code looks nice and familiar:

```
(pcre-match-string "\\A(\\d+)-(\\d+)-(\\d+)\\z" str)
```

But there is no installation instructions. My knowledge of installing Emacs packages is pretty limited (to ELPA).

Does anyone have experience installing/using the package, and can provide some instructions on this?

My environment is Ubuntu Linux 16.04 with its default Emacs 24.5

Answer (score 0):

Download emacs-pcre, and add the path to the pcre as:
https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LoadPath

Or you can just put the *.el files to /usr/local/share/emacs/VERSION/site-lisp or /usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp